# Official Documentation and Database Properties Window in Visio 2013

Tags: documentation, ms-office, visio

Where is the Database Properties window in Visio 2013? I see nowhere to set properties for an entity (keys and attributes). There's no official documentation from Microsoft that I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the following [Visio Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/visio/archive/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio.aspx).
To me, it looks like many features have been deprecated in Visio 2013 - specially the ones related to SW & DB diagramming capabilities.

Since Viso 2013 does not fit my developer needs, I end up downgrading to Visio 2010.
Hope this is helpful...

Comment: @Francisco...My mind is completely blown at what I just read. I've already downgrade, but this is just mind-boggling that they would do such a thing.

Comment: Why would they remove one of the most commonly used features in Visio???

Answer (score 1):

The quickest I have found, so far, is to hover over the bottom right corner of the entity box for 2 seconds (give or take).  Then a red line pops up, you click on that red line and it adds a new attribute.  I'm not saying this is great, but it is the best I've found.  I may be going back to 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click on the shape and select Data and other properties.